# Ошибка при запуске Activity

Tags: android, activity

```
Process: com.example.imatematik02, PID: 2358
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.imatematik02/com.example.imatematik02.GameActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1794)
at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1512)
at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3917)
at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityJB.startActivityForResult(BaseFragmentActivityJB.java:48)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:75)
at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3877)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:856)
at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4200)
at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4168)
at com.example.imatematik02.MenuActivity.startPlay(MenuActivity.java:41)
at com.example.imatematik02.MenuActivity.access$000(MenuActivity.java:13)
at com.example.imatematik02.MenuActivity$1.onClick(MenuActivity.java:29)
at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$AlertParams$3.onItemClick(AlertController.java:1108)
at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:310)
at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1145)
at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:3042)
at android.widget.AbsListView.onTouchUp(AbsListView.java:3891)
at android.widget.AbsListView.onTouchEvent(AbsListView.java:3656)
at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:9294)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2547)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2240)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2553)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2254)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2553)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2254)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2553)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2254)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2553)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2254)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2553)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2254)
at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2403)
at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1737)
at android.app.Dialog.dispatchTouchEvent(Dialog.java:787)
at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2364)
at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:9514)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4230)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:4096)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3642)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3695)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3661)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3787)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3669)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3844)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3642)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3695)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3661)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3669)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3642)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5922)
```

Comment: Обратите внимание на эту строчку: `Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.imatematik02/com.example.imatematik02.GameActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?`. Вы объявили Вашу `GameActivity` в `AndroidManifest.xml`?

Comment: Код того Макета.

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/app_back"
    android:orientation="vertical">

Ошибка в макете: Exception raised during rendering: Binary XML file line #-1: Error inflating class <unknown>